# SQL Server Management Studio diagram gui component

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, components

This is what I mean;

[image: MSSQL Management Studio diagram gui component]

Is it possible to use it in Visual Studio form designer? If it is, where is this library/component?

Comment: You mean you want a database scheme diagram drawing user control ?

Comment: I exactly want what image shows in a windows form I created. With drag/drop and resize (and maybe auto-arrange) functions of course. But I have nothing to do with database, I will give necessary data from another source.

Comment: try the project i showed in the answer i just posted...

Answer (score 0):

There is a project that will Rflect a given Assembly and create a class diagram...
if you have some time you could extract the GUI component hat draws the diagram ... 
I havat tryed that myself but i believe it sould work ...

[Reflective Class Diagram](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17823/100-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool)

Comment: I want to use standart one if exists, if not I will extend DataGrid view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it, in Visual Studio there is "Server explorer" view, in that you'll connect to database, after that you can create diagram.

Comment: I do not want to use the tool, I want to use its component. I think you misunderstand the question.